# Use Fn Keys, but keep Playback Keys

Tags: keyboard, settings, development, sound-volume

I'm a programmer, so it'd be useful for me to have access to `F1`, `F2`, etc.  while working on my laptop (a 2013 Macbook Air).  That said, I'm not really willing to give up the music or volume control keys.

Is there a way to bind `F7-F11` to their respective OS X specific features?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Install [KeyRemap4MacBook](https://pqrs.org/osx/karabiner/files/KeyRemap4MacBook-8.4.0.dmg) (for Mac OS X 10.4-10.8) or [Karabiner](https://pqrs.org/osx/karabiner/files/Karabiner-10.6.0.dmg) (for Mac OS X 10.9-10.10).

After the install is completed open KeyRemap4MacBook/Karabiner -> Preferences and the tab Change Key.

Scroll to "Change F1...F19 Key & Functional Key..." and enable the settings you want. The modified settings might conflict with keyboard shortcuts activated in the System Preferences. There are already a lot pre-sets but you may also create a custom set [with a private.xml](https://pqrs.org/osx/karabiner/xml.html.en).

[image]

Comment: Thank you! I already have Karabiner, and I absolutely love it.  It's a fantastic piece of software.  Do you know a good resource to learn to write my own private.xml file?

Comment: @Brandon The only one I know of is the linked [reference manual](https://pqrs.org/osx/karabiner/xml.html.en).

Answer (score 1):

If you just flip the function?

Enable F keys.

Now use fn + Volume keys.